# Lambda function as a small function argument

Tags: python, lambda

I'm doing some tutorial on greedy algorithms and I came across `lambda` function passed as a key parameter in sorted(). I thought I understood how they work (on simple examples like `lambda a,b: a+b`), but now I'm confused, why the last line works `test_greedy(foods, max_cost, lambda x: 1/Food.get_cost(x))`.
I get that `x` must be passed because of `self` and it's actually type `Food`. What is unclear to me is how and when `x` gets instantiated.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, value, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.calories = weight

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.calories

def greedy(items, max_cost, key_function):
    """
    key_function maps elements of items to numbers, tells what is meant by "BEST"
    """
    items_copy = sorted(items, key = key_function, reverse = True)

    result = []
    total_value, total_cost = 0.0, 0.0

    for i in range(len(items_copy)):
        if (total_cost+items_copy[i].get_cost()) <= max_cost:
            result.append(items_copy[i])
            total_cost += items_copy[i].get_cost()
            total_value += items_copy[i].get_value()

    return (result, total_value)

def use_greedy(max_cost):
    print("Use greedy by cost to allocate", max_cost, "calories")
    test_greedy(foods, max_cost, lambda x: 1/Food.get_cost(x))
```

Comment: Note, it should just be `lambda x: 1/ x.get_cost()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, I just put the original code here, probably the idea was to make clear where the method is defined since it is a learning example. But yes it should be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda gets evaluated when you call `test_greedy` with that as the argument.  It becomes a function descriptor assigned to `key_function`.  Note that `x` is still an unbound parameter at this point.

When you later pass that function to `sorted` as the sort key, *then* it gets called to evaluate each comparison between the elements of `items`.  One by one, they are passed as `x` to be evaluated, with `1/Food.get_cost(x)` being the numerical value used to sort the elements.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Yes, yes, it makes sense now. It is only passed (not called) in `use_greedy`. Thank you for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `test_greedy` function invokes `greedy` function with `foods` as the `items` argument, the lambda will be invoked with each element of `foods` in `items_copy = sorted(items, key = key_function, reverse = True)`.